# Replace multiple words in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file where I have to replace multiple words.

Code so far:

```
    NUMBEROFAPNS = raw_input("Please enter the APNS needed in the LTE profile: ")
    NUMBEROFAPNS = int(NUMBEROFAPNS)
    i = 0
    for i in range(NUMBEROFAPNS):
        APNS[i] = raw_input("enter the APN" + str(i+1))
        i = i + 1

    n = 0
    for n in range(NUMBEROFAPNS): 
       REPLACEAPN_input= (dict.values(APNS))[0]



       MAKEITDEFAULT_input=int(0+1)
       APNheader = str(pwd) + "/APNCREATION.txt"
       APNread = open(APNheader, "r")
       s=APNread.read()



       reps= {'REPLACEAPN':REPLACEAPN_input,'MADEIT':str(MAKEITDEFAULT_input),}
       txt = self.replace_all(s, reps)
       print txt 





def replace_all(self, text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
        return text
```

Text file being read looks like this

```
<epsPdnContext>
<apn>REPLACEAPN</apn>
<contextId>MADEIT</contextId>
```

I'm able to replace the `REPLACEAPN` word here to whatever input I have given but the `MADEIT` word is not replaced at all.
Kindly let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You don't have `MADEIT` key in `reps` dictionary.

Comment: sorry..i have made some mistakes while copying the code in the post.please see the correct code.I wanted to replace MADEIT with integer 1 but its not working

Comment: Are you sure you don't have mistakes in it now?

Comment: I believe so.this is now my code looks now.still the MADEIT word is not getting replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your return statement is inside the for loop. If you move it out (that is, de-indent it by one tab), it should work.